# Adding logging to Chi router

Tags: go

I'm attempting to set up logging using `httplog` for a Chi service that was generated with oapi-codegen, but structured logging isn't showing up in the console. When I use `fmt.Println` I can see those statements in the console.

The oapi-codegen `config.yaml` looks like this:

```
package: main
generate:
  chi-server: true
  embedded-spec: true
  models: true
```

Here's what I've tried thus far:

In `main.go`, we have:

```golang
func main() {
    s, err := NewAccountServer(myAwesomeConnectionString)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    logger := httplog.NewLogger("httplog-example", httplog.Options{
        JSON: true,
    })

    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.RequestID)
    r.Use(httplog.RequestLogger(logger))
    r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)

    h := Handler(s)
    r.Mount("/", h)

    var server = &http.Server{
        Handler: h,
        Addr:    "0.0.0.0:3000",
    }
    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
}
```

This stands up the server and it's able to serve requests just fine. Here's an example handler:

```golang
func (a AccountServer) GetAccountsEmail(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params GetAccountsEmailParams) {
    oplog := httplog.LogEntry(r.Context())
    oplog.Debug().Msgf("Finding user by ID ", params.AccountId.String())
    prefs, err := a.db.GetByAccountId(context.TODO(), params.AccountId)
    if err != nil {
        oplog.Debug().Err(err)
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
    }

    oplog.Debug().Msgf("Found them!")
    prefsJson, err := json.Marshal(prefs)
    if err != nil {
        oplog.Info().Err(err)
        w.Write([]byte(err.Error()))
    }
    oplog.Info().Msg(string(prefsJson))
    w.Write(prefsJson)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick was to re-read the [example code for the petstore application](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen/blob/master/examples/petstore-expanded/chi/petstore.go).

Where did I go wrong? I wasn't setting up the handler correctly. Instead of

```
h := Handler(s)
r.Mount("/", h)

var server = &http.Server{
    Handler: h,
    Addr:    "0.0.0.0:3000",
}
```

I needed to do:

```
HandlerFromMux(s, r)

var server = &http.Server{
    Handler: r,
    Addr:    "0.0.0.0:3000",
}
log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
```